# Django staticfiles not loading in AWS ec2

Tags: django, nginx, ec2-ami

I've deployed a django webiste in AWS ec2 with the help of this [digitalocean blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04) but the static files like css and javascripts are not loading after deployment.

This is my django static code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

MEDIA_ROOT =  'media/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

and this is my nginx code:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /staticfiles/ {
        root /home/sammy/project/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

And I'm using AWS S3 to host my static files.

Comment: Can you run `service nginx status` and see the error code? If it is permission denied then you may need to create a new directory elsewhere that nginx can access or give nginx access to the current static folder

Comment: There seem to  be  no  error

Comment: have u found any solution ??